# WinRT apps: ComboxBox and ListBox does not display anything when ItemsSource is List<Type>

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, listbox, windows-runtime

I tried to use `ListBox` to display a set of `Type` names
in XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="box"></ListBox>
```

and in code behind

```
box.ItemsSource= new List<Type>(){typeof(double), typeof(int)};
```

But the `ListBox` is displays empty string, although I can feel that there are indeed two items in the `Items` list and can click.

Even if I change the `ItemTemplate` to the following, the `FullName` property of class `Type` is not shown

```
<ListBox x:Name="box">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullName}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What is going on here? The following shows the name, but is not what I want. I want `Type` to be stored.

```
box.ItemsSource= new List<string>(){typeof(double).FullName, typeof(int).FullName};
```

(I tried `ComboBox`, which has the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

This is really strange, there are no binding errors at all. I don't know why it happens when you bind to a `Type` object directly (maybe it has something to do with the `System` namespace), but there is a workaround which is to create a wrapper class:

```
public class TypeWrapper
{
    private Type _type;

    public TypeWrapper(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

    public Type Type { get { return _type; } }
}
```

Then you create the `ItemsSource` as following:

```
box.ItemsSource = new List<TypeWrapper>()
            {
                new TypeWrapper(typeof (double)),
                new TypeWrapper(typeof (int))
            };
```

And in your XAML you use

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Type.FullName}"></TextBlock>
```

instead of

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: hi thanks. You method definitely works. Let's wait to see whether some guys know the reason. It curious of knowing the reason. It frustrated me very much.